# ctypes and building metaclasses: TypeError: *class* instance instead of LP_*class* instance

Tags: python, c, ctypes, typeerror, metaclass

**Story:** I'm using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to communicate from python to C and the other way around. I'm also making the C shared library I'm trying to interface too. At this step of development it's just a simple library to test all the concepts before diving into code. The library it's written in C++ exposing functions with extern "C", nothing fancy. I have tested functions with primitive parameters / return types, pointers and function callbacks.

Now I want to pass structs. Since I'm a lazy programmer I'm planning to pass C++ structs to a uniform C representation (ie. a combination of simple dictionary and lists) and handle that to python, which will convert that into a real python  object (ie. a python combination of dictionary and lists).

**Problem:** To achieve this first I defined a templated dictionary in C++, its implementation is, just for testing, a linked list of key-value pairs, with the dictionary owning the root. Then, for every function that needs a specialization, a typedef of that specialization is used as a C struct.

The code looks like this (not actual code):

```
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename key_t, typename value_t>
struct DictNode
{
    key_t key;
    value_t value;
};

template <typename key_t, typename value_t>
struct Dict
{
    typedef DictNode<key_t, value_t> node_t;
    node_t root;
};

typedef Dict<int, char> Dict_int_char;

extern "C" Dict_int_char* example_new()
{
    Dict_int_char* result;
    result = (Dict_int_char*)malloc(sizeof(Dict_int_char));
    return result;
}

extern "C" void example_delete(Dict_int_char* value)
{
    free(value);
}
```

Now, in python, to avoid creating a class for every specialization, I'm following the same approach. A method will create for me the specialized class given the key-value types.

The code looks like this (actual code):

```
import types
import ctypes

# This is to provide some hiding of the module internals
# Suggestions on a more pythonic way are gladly accepted
class __Internals:
  """
  Creates class to interface with a C structure comming from a
  typedef'd C++ class template specialization. This method recieves
  the types of the template class, creates the ctypes classes to
  interface with the specialized class (which has been typedef'd)
  and returns them for usage with ctypes.
  """
  @staticmethod
  def __DictClassCreate__(key_t, value_t):
    # Foward declare the classes
    class InterfaceListNode(ctypes.Structure):
      pass;
    class InterfaceList(ctypes.Structure):
      pass;

    #### NODE
    # Node class
    nodeType = InterfaceListNode;
    # The pointer-to-node class 
    nodeTypePointerType = ctypes.POINTER(nodeType);
    # Fields of the node class (next, key, value)
    nodeType._fields_ = [("next", nodeTypePointerType),
                         ("key", key_t),
                         ("value", value_t) ];

    # Function to create a node pointer
    def nodeTypePointerCreate(cls, value=None):
      if(value is None):
        return nodeTypePointerType();
      else:
        return nodeTypePointerType(value);

    # Bind the function to the node class
    nodeType.pointer = types.MethodType(nodeTypePointerCreate, nodeType);

    #### DICT
    # Dict class
    dictType = InterfaceList;
    # The pointer-to-dict class 
    dictTypePointerType = ctypes.POINTER(dictType);
    # Useful for dict to know the types of it's nodes
    dictType._nodeType = nodeType;
    # Fields of the dict class (root)
    dictType._fields_ = [("root", ctypes.POINTER(nodeType))];

    # Function to create a dict pointer
    def dictTypePointerCreate(cls, value=None):
      if(value is None):
        return dictTypePointerType();
      else:
        return dictTypePointerType(value);

    # Bind the function to the dict class
    dictType.pointer = types.MethodType(dictTypePointerCreate, dictType);    

    # For debugging
    print 'Inside metaclass generator'
    print hex(id(nodeType));
    print hex(id(dictType));

    # Return just the dict class since it knows about it's node class.
    return dictType;

# Create a new specialized dict<c_uint, c_char>
dictType_1 = __Internals.__DictClassCreate__(ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_char);
# Obtain the node type of this dict
nodeType_1 = dictType_1._nodeType;

# For debugging
print 'In Script'
print hex(id(nodeType_1));
print hex(id(dictType_1));

# Try to instance this dictionary with 1 element
#(not NULL root, NULL root.next)
dict_1 = dictType_1(nodeType_1(nodeType_1.pointer(), 0, 'a'));
```

When this code runs, the following output is displayed:

```
python SciCamAPI.py
Inside metaclass generator
0x249c1d8L
0x249c588L
In Script
0x249c1d8L
0x249c588L
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SciCamAPI.py", line 107, in <module>
    dict_1 = dictType_1(nodeType_1(nodeType_1.pointer(), 0, 'a'));
TypeError: incompatible types, InterfaceListNode instance instead of LP_InterfaceListNode instance
```

From the printed output I can see I'm using the same metaclasses to instance the simple dict and it's nodes as the one generated in the method.

I've googled what can be the LP_ appended in the error, but searching LP_ python only returns linear problem solvers and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697065/whats-the-difference-between-lp-pointers-and-p-pointers-in-ctypes-and-wei). From what understand of the answer ctypes is creating a C-styled pointer from nodeType_1.pointer() (last line), but thats is what is supposed to be received when the node.next was declared as [("next", nodeTypePointerType),...] (in nodeType.*fields*=...). So I'm pretty lost.

Comment: `dictType_1.root` is an `LP_InterfaceListNode` field, i.e. `POINTER(InterfaceListNode)`, but you're initializing it with an `InterfaceListNode` instead of a pointer to one. "LP" is for "long pointer" from back in the day of segmented architectures that had near (within segment) and far/long pointers. Windows types retain this prefix even though it's no longer meaningful, such as `LPVOID` and `LPWSTR`. ctypes was initially a Windows-only package.

Comment: Thanks, thats, it! Replacing last line with: `rootNode = nodeType_1(nodeType_1.pointer(), 0, 'a');
dict_1 = dictType_1(nodeType_1.pointer(rootNode));`, does it. Should you post an anwser to accept it or I make it quoting you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing the comment of eryksun:

> `dictType_1.root` is an `LP_InterfaceListNode` field, i.e. `POINTER(InterfaceListNode)`, but you're initializing it with an `InterfaceListNode` instead of a pointer to one. "LP" is for "long pointer" from back in the day of segmented architectures that had near (within segment) and far/long pointers. Windows types retain this prefix even though it's no longer meaningful, such as `LPVOID` and `LPWSTR`. ctypes was initially a Windows-only package

So I missed to convert `dictType_1.root` to a pointer. Changing the last line to:

```
rootNode = nodeType_1(nodeType_1.pointer(), 0, 'a');
dict_1 = dictType_1(nodeType_1.pointer(rootNode));
```

Solves the problem.