# convert LP_c_char to something meaning full as string or list

Tags: python, c++, sip

I am casting a sip object, which is a buffer of char's to ctypes u_byte type, which results in the following object:

```
<ctypes.LP_c_char object at 0x23b95560>
```

For debugging purposes, I would like to access its content. I've read [What's the difference between LP_* pointers and *_p pointers in ctypes? (and weird interaction with structs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697065/whats-the-difference-between-lp-pointers-and-p-pointers-in-ctypes-and-wei) that article but wasn't helpfull.

Any idea how to use LP_c_char type to convert it to a python string or a list of char's?